# How can a mod undelete a question if they have already cast an undelete vote before becoming a mod?

Tags: support, moderation, vote-to-delete, undelete

Assume that a user cast an undelete vote on a post. The user later became a mod and now wants to use their mod powers to undelete that post. How can they do so?

Comment: This looks to be derived from [my reply](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4491/overzealous-app-recommendation-closing-deleting/4492?noredirect=1#comment5810_4492) to a comment that I posted 7 hours ago. Is that correct?

Comment: @Rubén [correct](https://web.archive.org/web/20231029221648/https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5137/why-did-a-moderator-close-this-12-year-old-google-search-question-yesterday-as-o/5138?noredirect=1#comment5813_5138).

Comment: @RobertLongson I have included some suggestions to the author of the comment. By the way, the related question to be undeleted is about an abandoned tag, `facebook`, that I added no remember when to my ignored tags. This tag has been getting new questions, but there is rarely activity around them. During 2022, most of them were deleted as abandoned. I will not bother my fellow mods with a question about a tag that no expert able to answer or curate cares about.

Comment: If there is any Facebook expert that likes curation, please take a look at [A task for the task jar: Clean up facebook questions and tags as they are bumped by Community user](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5152/88163)

Comment: It's worth noting that yesterday, it was declared that the discussion about the Web Applications research policy, connects the people engaged in this (the commenter to whom I replied, the OP, etc.). Long story short, there is a wicked problem (a social problem that is impossible to solve; the only thing possible to do is navigate through it). Concerning the deleted question, it is a question about Facebook, as I mentioned above. I just posted [According to the statistics, Facebook users have moved from desktop to mobile](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5169/88163)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They... should still be able to undelete it.

Moderators bypass most of the permissions checks on casting delete/undelete votes, *including the check on whether they've already cast a vote*. They would never receive an error saying they've already cast a delete/undelete vote because that error is behind an `if (!u.IsModerator)` check that would never fire.

Simply clicking the button again to try casting an undelete vote a second time should just cause it to be undeleted without issue. At worst, the client-side scripting might force them to retract the vote and then cast it again (though I believe client-side is scripted to just always submit it and see what the server says), but the server-side permissions absolutely allow them to do this without issue.

Comment: The “convert answer to comment” logic is slightly broken, letting me get [posts](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/12413/278) into this state without returning / re-requesting my diamond – and it looks like you're right about the client-side behaviour. (I coulda sworn I remembered it working differently.) Awaiting confirmation from another mod.

Comment: I'm user/moderator who is this question talking about. The deleted question might not be worthy to be undeleated. I updated the answer on the Meta site that derived this question explaining the reasons.. I have added comments to the question with related links. Please excuse me that I don't confirm

Answer (score 9):

Ask one of your fellow moderators to help you by undeleting the post for you. If they aren't around, ask a [Community Manager](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-is-on-the-community-management-team-and-what-does-it-do) for help.

The same problem can occur with approving suggested edits if you've already cast a non-binding approval vote.